# How to handle "class type redefinition"

Tags: c++

I've trying to work with an open source VC++ code.
I'm trying to add a new project to an existing VC++ solution which turned to be a nightmare.
One of the problems I'm facing is fixing "type redefinition" errors, I already fixed a few but now I'm stuck on some others. The code base is huge so no snippests...

My questions is, is there any "best practice" to track down these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By type redefinition, I assume that there are same name `class`es or `typedef`s defined in your workspace projects and they are causing problem while compilation (not to confuse with multiple definition linker error).

The best practice is to always enclose them into **`namespace`** on module or project bases.
e.g.

```
// project1.h
namespace project1 {
  class X {};
}

// project2.h
namespace project2 {
  class X {};
}
```

Comment: 10x, Please see my comment to @sharptooth. The "included" code is not mine so I can't add namespaces. I'm just looking for a way to track down the redefinitions.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to put all code in the separate projects in separate namespaces. Then you wouldn't have to worry about clashes. It might be a lot of work if you have a lot of header and source files, but it might be worth it in the long run.

And you don't have to add the namespace to all functions/classes, just add `namespace foo {` at the top in all header/source file, and a corresponding `}` at the bottom.

Comment: 10x. Please see my comment to @sharptooth

Answer (score 0):

When you try to include the same header file in two or more different programs, like 
A calling B and B calling C, and if you include C in both A and B, then this kind of error occur. same happened with me, and resolved it.